# ajaxForm not callingBack

Tags: jquery, ajax, ajaxform

I know that this is already covered by a lot of you and in hundreds of posts but I didn't see anyone with a problem like I'm having.

I'm trying to implement the AjaxForm to upload files. I read all the tutorials, documentation, examples ... everything.

HTML:

```
<form action="scripts/upload_script.php" method='post' id="upload_picture_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    File: <input type="file" name="upload" id="upload" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name='submit' value="Submit" /></p>
</form>
```

Jquery:

```
$('#upload_picture_form').ajaxForm({
  success: function(){
    alert('success');
  },
  error: function(){
    alert('error');
  },
  resetForm:true
});
```

When I submit the form, the ajaxForm is called, on fireBug I can see the php file been called and I can also see that the response is '200 OK' after a few 'ms' and I can see the response in HTML sent by the php.

The problem is after the response no 'success' or 'error' is triggered, the form is no reseted ... looks like there is no callback.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Does the 'echo' from the php has to be in some specific format? I'm sending a simple "File: image.jpg (7487 bytes)" back to the jQuery.

Regards.

Comment: try adding the `resetForm:true` inside `success`/`error` scope

Comment: `success`, `error`, `complete` are itself callbacks.

Comment: None of the `success` or `error` is been called.

Answer (score 0):

here is the small example of `ajaxFrom` that return the callback event as well:

```
<form id="imageform" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="get_img.php" method="post">
 <tr>
   <td valign="top"><label>Select File</label> :</td>
   <td><input type="file" name="myfile" id="myfile" /> <br />
   <em>.jpeg, .jpg, .gif, .png, .bmp</em>
   </td>
 </tr>
</form>

<div id="result"></div>
```

now working with jquery :

```
$(function(){
$('#myfile').live({
    change: function(){
            $('#result').ajaxStart(function(){
                $(this).html('<div class="loader" />');
            });

            $('#imageform').ajaxForm({
                                 target: '#result', 
                                 success: function(){ // Call Back Function } 
                            }).submit();
        }
});
});
```

the purpose of implementing the `ajaxFrom` here to submit the image without click event, and in the above jquery codes, i have attached the event on `Change`, the form is submitted automatically and call the `get_img.php` which is in action.

on the `target` you get what you have returned through the file `get_img.php`,
and on `success` you set any callback, method that you want.

Comment: Hi Jogesh_p, thank you for your reply. Can I ask you for a simple example what could be the **get_img.php** just to see if it's something i may be doing wrong on the php.

Comment: @user1141673 follow the link : http://blog.webtech11.com/2012/03/18/ajax-based-instant-image-upload.html

Comment: Just don't see how to implement. Where's the `$(document).ready(function(){` ?

Comment: @jogesh_g I'm new to this, can you explain your suggestion?

Comment: @user1141673 `$(function(){})` and `$(document).ready(function(){})` is same, you don't have to confuse with this.