# Ajax form post not posting input type with file

Tags: jquery, ajax

"i have simple form and posting it with ajax, but i am not able to get the $_FILES in php script"

```
<form id="submitForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
     <input type="file" name="file"  />
     <input type="text" name="name" />
    </form>
```

below is ajax code,tell me where i am mistaken

```
$.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>getter/addItemRow',
                type:"POST",
                data:$('#submitForm').serialize(),
                context: $('#table')
                }).done(function(data) {
                  this.prepend(data);
                });
```

below is php code line

```
print_r(var_dump($_FILES));
```

this is returning empty array;

Comment: You cannot send a file throught ajax

Comment: there is no other way to workaround

Comment: Use Iframe for upload and reload it

Comment: use ajaxForm plugin to do this..

Comment: @jogesh_p will those plugin will be cross browser ... if there is anyone can you provide me link of that

Comment: @SandeepKumar You can use `jQuery Form Plugin` to work on. Please check the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 


$(function() { 
    $('#submitForm').ajaxForm(function(result) {
                    $("#HiddenRowsa").hide();
                    $('#table').prepend(result);
                }).submit();
         });
```

all the answers that i got that were all same and **RIGHT**,this the simple jquery code that will work,all the links that are provided here, were missing .submit() function in the of the ajaxForm,so all the others who are looking for this kind of problem first include the above file in the head then write the above code

Comment: Were the `input[type=text]` and `input[type=file]` submitted together?

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you please check out my [problem here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834569/sending-inputtype-file-through-ajax-to-codeigniter-using-jquery-form)? I tried your answer but it does not work for me.

Comment: have u used the above code?, and have u included the script that first line in this answer?

Comment: Yes sir. It can't pick up the `input[type=file]`.

Comment: enctype="multipart/form-data" maybe u were missing this in ur form tag, many time i aslo forget to write this line too

Comment: Here is the link of my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834569/sending-inputtype-file-through-ajax-to-codeigniter-using-jquery-form

Answer (score 3):

#### You cannot use AJAX / JavaScript to transfer files!

**AJAX**, which is just **JavaScript**, cannot access files stored in the file system and transfer it to the server. You can use hidden iframes to do this. There's a nice [jquery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) which allows you to make your forms look and feel like it is AJAX and it [supports file uploads](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload) as well.

#### The code used by this plugin is very simple:

```
$(function() {
    $('#formid').bind("submit", function(){
        $(this).ajaxForm(function(result) {
            alert('the form was successfully posted!');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the info a +1, well your answer is almost correct but it has to be .submit() in the end after which it will be post

Comment: if u can correct your answer what i pointed i'll accept ur answer, bcoz i don't want that anybody comes searching this kind of problem  and dn't get full answer,

Answer (score 2):

file upload is NOT possible through ajax. You can upload file, without refreshing page by using IFrame. you can check further details here:

http://www.ajaxf1.com/tutorial/ajax-file-upload-tutorial.html

With XHR2, File upload through AJAX is supported. for example  through FormData object, but unfortunately it is not supported by all/old browsers.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery cannot handle PHP files with simply AJAX because $_FILES is a global PHP variable that has nothing to do with javascript at all. You could use a plugin like this one: [jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/), or tons more. Just [search and find on google](http://www.google.nl/search?client=opera&rls=nl&q=jquery+file+upload&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest#hl=nl&client=opera&hs=Eqi&rls=nl&channel=suggest&sclient=psy-ab&q=jquery+file+uploader&oq=jquery+file+uploader&gs_l=serp.3...76685.76740.0.77131.2.2.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0...1c.1.YGILz80S40E&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=da33171a4440e23e&bpcl=35277026&biw=1920&bih=991).

You could also use iFrames for it, but I do not recommend it because in IE it gives that nasty *click* like the page has changed.

Answer (score 0):

here is an alternative solution, if you want to upload the file instantly, use ajaxForm to do so, in the following link you find the [ajaxForm not callingBack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12814590/ajaxform-not-callingback/12815294#12815294)

Here is the link of the ajaxForm to know more about the methods:: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#ajaxForm