# Sending input[type=file] through ajax to CodeIgniter using jQuery.form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, codeigniter

Here is the basic `html` form:

```
<?php echo form_open( 'controller' ); ?>  
  <fieldset>
    <input type="text" name="field_name_1" value="<?php echo set_value('field_name_1'); ?>"/>
    <input type="file" name="field_name_2" value="<?php echo set_value('field_name_2'); ?>"/>
    // more dynamically added form fields
    <input type="submit" />
  </fieldset>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

**I want my `input[type=file]` to be sent to its controller (together with the other input types as one) via `ajax` and the [jQuery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/).**

I have the code below that works on all the other input types except for `input[type=file]`.

```
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 

var options = {
    url: "<?php echo site_url('new_account/validate_new_account'); ?>",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {

      if (data.length === 0) {
        alert('Form successfully submitted!');
      } else {
        alert("Some fields weren't answered successfully. Please answer them.");
        // attach server-side form validations to respective fields
        $.each(data, function(key, value){
          var container = '<div class="error">'+value+'</div>';
          $('.form-element input[name="'+key+'"]').after(container);
        });
      }

    }
};

$('#main-submit').click(function(e) {
  $('#professional-form').valid(); // jQuery validate
  $('#professional-form').ajaxSubmit(options);  
  e.preventDefault(); // redirect to other place only if successful form 
});
```

The other input fields are sent successfully but **CodeIgniter still does not receive the file**. Do you guys know how to fix this?

Comment: need to see ur html code too

Comment: @Sandeep Kumar - I added my `html` code

Comment: first try using basic html form tag instead of codeigniter, and don't forget to add enctype="multipart/form-data"  in the form attributes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File upload is not generally possible via standard ajax posting. However there are certain tools out there that allow asynchronous uploading of files:

- http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/
- http://www.plupload.com/

The reason you can't do this using a standard jquery post is because javascript can't read local files for security reasons.  These tools get around the limitation using various solutions such as hidden iframes, Flash, or HTML5 techniques, depending on what is available on the browser.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
So that means I cannot send all my multi-part's form values in one process? :(
I mean I have to separate the file uploads in another form?

Comment: I've only used JQuery-File-Upload. With that you can submit additional POST data along with the file, so you can submit it all in one go, but it will have to be via the async file upload tool.

Comment: By the way I think plupload is the more advanced and probably better supported of these two, and I expect you can also submit additional form data using it. So if I had to choose now I'd start with that one.

Comment: Just a note, you *can* upload files with ajax, however, it is not supported in IE < 10 (for the other browsers, you have to use window.formData). For IE<10, you will have to submit the form with files to a hidden iframe instead.

Answer (score 0):

File upload is possible via ajax with jquery.form.js as mentioned on the following link:

http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload